# How would I get the value inside the array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I would like to get the value of `[source]` inside the cover array. What should I do? Thanks.

```
Array
(
    [cover] => Array
    (
        [id] => 763132827070934
        [offset_y] => 29
        [source] => https://scontent-a.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xap1/t31.0-8/q71/s720x720/10507065_763132827070934_644083226197727503_o.jpg
    )

    [id] => 123456789000
)
```

Comment: `$array['cover']['source']` - go ahead (answer storm is coming)

Comment: Its so simple :) - `$data['cover']['source']`

Comment: @LynerKharl Please always accept answers which help you as it shows that your problem is solved and then no one will invest time on it :)

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
$array['cover']['source'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$data = Array
     (
        [cover] => Array
        (
            [id] => 763132827070934
            [offset_y] => 29
            [source] => https://scontent-a.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xap1/t31.0-8/q71/s720x720/10507065_763132827070934_644083226197727503_o.jpg
        )

         [id] => 123456789000
      )

echo $data['cover']['source'];
?>
```